# Optimize SPARQL query performance issue

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology

I am looking to optimize the below query,currently the query takes about 1m 20sec with about 213500 triples I am looking for any optimization suggestion for the query

I know that Optional takes most of the time here but is there any other option to get similar result set?

I have also attached our resource mapping in the picture

[image: Here is design for our reources]

```
CONSTRUCT
{
  ?cref ?p  ?o .
  ?o    ?p1 ?o1 .
  ?o    ?p2 ?o2 .
  ?o2   ?p3 ?o3 .
}
WHERE
  {
    {
      SELECT DISTINCT ?cref
      WHERE {
              { ?cref xyz:hasSourceBrand xyz:abc .}
              union
              { ?cref xyz:hasTargetBrand xyz:abc .}
              VALUES ?o1 { "New" "Validated" } 
              ?cref xyz:CrossReferenceStatus ?o1 .
            }
    }
    ?cref ?p ?o .
    {
      ?cref ?p ?o .
    }
    UNION
    {
      ?o a xyz:Part .
      OPTIONAL { ?o ?p1 ?o1 .}
    }
    UNION
    {
      ?o a xyz:CrossReferenceRelation .
      OPTIONAL { ?o  ?p2 ?o2 .}
      OPTIONAL { ?o2 a   xyz:author ; 
                     ?p3 ?o3 .
               }
    }
  }
```

Comment: There is no generally meaningful way to answer this, as the performance will depend on what RDF database you're using and what the size and shape of your data is. Most databases will have an query plan explain feature though that you can use to analyze the query and see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: in addition to what Jeen said,  1) your query is weird, where is `?triples` bound in the `WHERE` part? And what is the point of `?cref ?p ?o .
     {
       ?cref ?p ?o .
     }` ? And why did you not put the optional pattern inside the other optional pattern: `OPTIONAL {?o ?p2 ?o2 .}
         OPTIONAL {?o2 a xyz:author ; ?p3 ?o3 .}` 3) instead of `FILTER( ?o1 in  ("New","Validated") )` why not using `VALUES`?

Comment: 1) sorry corrected my query for ?triples it is ?cref  2) initially dint have the part but seems like the graph dint include the predicates for ?cref so I included it that way ..may be it is not the right way to do it (if you can help me also to correct it ) 3) are you saying to add both the triple patterns inside a same optional bracket? because when I try to do that I dont receive the desired result incase any value is missing 4) I can change the filter to values 4)

Comment: As @JeenBroekstra I am currently using Neptune here of course the same query gives better results on other triple stores but is there something that I am doing wrong here? I checked the query explain the feature and it showed the max time taken is in the line with OPTIONAL so is there a better way to optimize it?

Comment: @UninformedUser updated the query for values now.

Comment: 1)You might look at the `EXPLAIN` output from engines that deliver faster results, as that may include optimizations made by those engines. 2) You said that *the max time taken is in the line with `OPTIONAL`* but you have several `OPTIONAL` clauses -- so is that max time on *one* of those clauses? If so, that should give you an idea of where to explore further. 3) This performance hit is one tradeoff of choosing Neptune. Other RDF stores that can be run in the cloud may serve you better. My employer offers one such, OpenLink Virtuoso, <http://dbpedia.org/page/Virtuoso_Universal_Server>.